# Does ginger's rhizome need to be cover?

Tags: planting, ginger

Last week, I have planted a dry old ginger that has kinda developed buds.. I planted it an inch deep as many guide on the internet has said but this left quite a lot of the rhizome expose which I cover...

But living in a tropical area means, there is rains, a lot of rains and whenever it rained, it wash all the dirt away exposing the rhizome... it is kinda annoying to cover the rhizome only to find it get wash off again the next day because it rained at night.

Is it necessary to always cover ginger rhizome with dirt? should I planted it deeper so the dirt didn't get wash away often?

Comment: Ginger naturally grows about one inch deep, the top of rhizome is about one inch below the surface . I have 3 types of ginger , they are all about the same .